# How to specify which database to audit in postgresql 12?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to audit connections to my postgres databases.
i got 32 databases in my installation and one postgresql.conf for all of them.

I've configured to
log_connections = on and now i got information in my file log about connections to 32 databases.
But that should i do to monitor only databases that i need?

For example i need to monitor connections only to 5 of them, other is not interesting for me.
Where should i configure it?

It would be really nice if i could do it in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 1):

with the log_connections parameter, you cannot leverage the granularity to audit selective databases. I would suggest you use [pg_audit](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/blob/master/README.md) extension

by default pgAudit will log all databases but you can change it to log per database by using

```
ALTER DATABASE <database name> set pgaudit.log='<value>';
```

If you are using it AWS RDS/AURORA refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-pgaudit/

For community Postgres you can use https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/blob/master/README.md